# How can I execute a python script from an html button?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a number of python scripts that I have saved on my computer, out of curiosity I have created a html file that just has one button. Instead on going into the terminal and running `python <path to script>`, I would like to make it so when that button is clicked, is kicks off one of my python scripts. Is this possible/how can it be done?

for example purposes we'll call the script to be run `MYSCRIPT.py`. I've done a little research but have come up with nothing promising. I'm aware the following code is incorrect but just for a starting point here is my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <head>

           <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="exec('python MYSCRIPT.py');">

        </head>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Webpages are not allowed to run shell commands, as that would e very dangerous. Image going to a site that can run any command in your shell. What you would need is a server, that you send a request to and the server runs the command there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python scripts from HTML button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894506/running-python-scripts-from-html-button)

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX to call the script.

Comment: Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166941/create-html-button-to-run-python-script) on another post, maybe it will help.

Comment: Body is after Head, not inside

Comment: I would run a jQuery AJAX call to the script itself .. This script will have to reside in the public `html` directory and accessible by a browser.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Doing this in HTML (and therefor in a browser) would be much more complicated than a basic UI built with something like WXPython https://www.wxpython.org/pages/overview/#hello-world

Comment: Windows, Linux, or Mac?

Comment: Wait, are you asking for an approach to run Python scripts locally or on a server remotely?

Comment: @JasonSperske locally for now

Comment: Then a UI framework like wxPytyon would be a lot cleaner, I'll work on a simple example of this...one sec

Comment: What do you ultimately want to accomplish with this? Because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949174/3491991) can do exactly what you want, just like a number of other frameworks (like the mentioned wxPython, Flask or Django). But each implementation varies in difficulty and aim...

Answer (score 30):

There are various ways to make it done, very simple technique with security peace in mind, here might help you

---

**1.** First you need to install **Flask** 
`pip install flask` or `pip3 install flask` 
in your command prompt, which is a python microframework, don't be afraid that you need to have another prior knowledge to learn that, it's really simple and just a few line of code.
*If you wish you learn Flask quickly for complete novice here is the tutorial that I also learn from [Flask Tutorial for beginner (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDi9F_slcQK7knjtO8TUvUs)*
**2.** Create a new folder

- 1st file will be
  **server.py**

```html
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/my-link/')
def my_link():
  print ('I got clicked!')

  return 'Click.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

- 2nd create another subfolder inside previous folder and name it as **templates** and create **index.html** file inside it

```html
<!doctype html>


<head><title>Test</title> 
    <meta charset=utf-8> </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Website</h1>
        <form action="/my-link/">
            <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
        </form>
        
        <button> <a href="/my-link/">Click me</a></button>

    </body>
```

**3.** To run, open command prompt to the **New Folder** you created earlier, type `python server.py` or `python3 server.py` to run the script, then you will get response in your terminal/command prompt  that server is running on `http://127.0.0.1:5000` or **any other ports**. After that you go to browser type `localhost:5000` or `http://127.0.0.1:5000`, then you will see button. You can click and route to destination script file you created.

Hope this helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Since you asked for a way to complete this within an `HTML` page I am answering this.  I feel there is no need to mention the severe warnings and implications that would go along with this .. I trust you know the security of your `.py` script better than I do :-)

I would use the `.ajax()` function in the `jQuery` library.  This will allow you to call your `Python` script **as long as the script is in the publicly accessible html directory**  ...  That said this is the part where I tell you to heed security precautions ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function goPython(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "MYSCRIPT.py",
             context: document.body
            }).done(function() {
             alert('finished python script');;
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In addition .. It's worth noting that your script is going to have to have proper permissions for, say, the `www-data` user to be able to run it ... A `chmod`, and/or a `chown` may be necessary.

Comment: this would mainly be dangerous if this is a script with a web server correct like flask or django? If this was just an simple html file and python file in the same directory running a script on a local machine... this would not be dangerous or am I missing something

Comment: The only security risk is that which is present for all server-side files.  If someone can access the file *directly* and manipulate inputs / injections to get a result that may display sensitive information like the server directory structure or tables within the database.

Comment: --  It's the programming **within** the `.py` file that can be the security risk if not properly locked down.  Usually if it's already part of a framework, most of those security concerns are already addressed within the framework.

Comment: understood. so assuming the only parts involved in the project are a simple html file with a button and  a python script that runs onclick from within  a local machine...the biggest security concern is someone unauthorized getting access to that file.

Comment: This does not work. I recieve a 405 error reponse. I think I need a backend solution in order to work, because calling a .py file from the frontend it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to Use a Python Web Frame Work you can choose **Django/Flask**. I will suggest you to Use **Django** because it's more powerful. 
Here is Step by guide to get complete your task :

```
pip install django
django-admin createproject buttonpython
```

then you have to create a file name views.py in buttonpython directory.

write below code in views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def sample(request):
    #your python script code
    output=code output
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Once done navigate to urls.py and add this stanza

```
from . import views

path('', include('blog.urls')),
```

Now go to parent directory and execute manage.py

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Step by Step Guide in Detail: [Run Python script on clicking HTML button](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERMRVORGvZM)

Answer (score 2):

This would require knowledge of a backend website language.

Fortunately, Python's [Flask Library](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a suitable backend language for the project at hand.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601478/flask-calling-python-function-on-button-onclick-event) from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

I've done exactly this on Windows.  I have a local .html page that I use as a "dashboard" for all my current work.  In addition to the usual links, I've been able to add clickable links that open MS-Word documents, Excel spreadsheets, open my IDE, ssh to servers, etc.  It is a little involved but here's how I did it ...

First, update the Windows registry.  Your browser handles usual protocols like http, https, ftp.  You can define your own protocol and a handler to be invoked when a link of that protocol-type is clicked.  Here's the config (run with `regedit`)

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mydb]
@="URL:MyDB Document"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mydb\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mydb\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mydb\shell\open\command]
@="wscript C:\_opt\Dashboard\Dashboard.vbs \"%1\""
```

With this, when I have a link like `<a href="mydb:open:ProjectX.docx">ProjectX</a>`, clicking it will invoke `C:\_opt\Dashboard\Dashboard.vbs` passing it the command line parameter `open:ProjectX.docx`.  My VBS code looks at this parameter and does the necessary thing (in this case, because it ends in .docx, it invokes MS-Word with `ProjectX.docx` as the parameter to it.

Now, I've written my handler in VBS only because it is very old code (like 15+ years).  I haven't tried it, but you might be able to write a Python handler, `Dashboard.py`, instead.  I'll leave it up to you to write your own handler.  For your scripts, your link could be `href="mydb:runpy:whatever.py"` (the `runpy:` prefix tells your handle to run with Python).

Answer (score 0):

It is discouraged and problematic yet doable. What you need is a custom URI scheme ie. You need to register and configure it on your machine and then hook an url with that scheme to the button.

URI scheme is the part before `://` in an URI. Standard URI schemes are for example `https` or `ftp` or `file`. But there are custom like fx. `mongodb`. What you need is your own e.g. `mypythonscript`. It can be configured to exec the script or even just python with the script name in the params etc. It is of course a tradeoff between flexibility and security.

You can find more details in the links:

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

**EDIT:** Added more details about what an custom scheme is.

Answer (score 0):

you could use text files to trasfer the data using PHP and reading the text file in python