# Can you execute python in html

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, cgi

Lets say I've written a simple html page with a form. The form has 3 input fields that a user fills and presses the submit button. Is it possible to take the values of the 3 input fields from html, use something like ajax in jquery and execute a python script whilst sending those form values to that script as variables?

Everywhere I read about this subject the guides always return the html code in the python script using Flask. Issue is I already have html and all I need is for this form to trigger a python script and just let the user know after pressing the button that the script has been executed. I really would hate to think I need to write my markup in python again!

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute a python script from an html button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button).

Comment: What is your server-side scripting language you're using for the site? If not Python, why do you specifically need to use Python? It's possible but if you're just using a standard setup (no frameworks) I feel like it would be easier for you to do this with something like a PHP script.

Comment: not all servers let you run Python script. It has to use CGI. And mostly script has to be in special folder. As for Flask - it doesn't have to send HTML - all depend on you. It can send JSON data which you can use with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [@Zak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507691/zak):

Since you asked for a way to complete this within an `HTML` page I am answering this.  I feel there is no need to mention the severe warnings and implications that would go along with this .. I trust you know the security of your `.py` script better than I do :-)

I would use the `.ajax()` function in the `jQuery` library.  This will allow you to call your `Python` script **as long as the script is in the publicly accessible html directory**  ...  That said this is the part where I tell you to heed security precautions ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function goPython(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "MYSCRIPT.py",
             context: document.body
            }).done(function() {
             alert('finished python script');;
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In addition .. It's worth noting that your script is going to have to have proper permissions for, say, the `www-data` user to be able to run it ... A `chmod`, and/or a `chown` may be necessary.