# Python script opens in gedit when called by my html script

Tags: python, html

I am just trying out a few things in Html, and I am very new to it. I tried to write a Html code that takes in input a string and calls a python script to find the frequency of all unicode characters in string. When I am running my html script, it tries to open gedit and show my python script, instead of running the script. How do I run the script, providing my arguments to it during the process?

This is my python code :

```py
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

#input_str=input("Enter the string\n")
def Frequency_match(input_str):
    flag=0
    count=0
    i=0
    j=0
    #print("Here\n")
    while i < len(input_str):
        #print("The current value of i is ",i,"\n")
        count=0
        j=0
        while j < len(input_str):
            if input_str[i]==input_str[j]:
                if j<i:
                    flag=1
                else:
                    count+=1
            j+=1
        if flag==0:
            print("The frequency of ",i," ",input_str[i],"is",count,"\n")
        i+=1
        #print("The value of i is ",i,"\n")
        flag=0

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
input_str = form.getvalue('input_str')

Frequency_match(input_str)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form action="./NLP_test.py" method="post">
    Input String: <input type="text" name="input_str"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="run_script" "/>
</form>

<p>Click on the submit button, and the input will be sent to a page on the server called "/NLP_test.py ".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the html script, I get asked if I want to open the python file in text editor

Comment: So, do you mean clicking the file by running the html script?

Comment: I give an input string , click the submit button, and the python script runs in the bg and gives the frequency of characters. Thats what I want to do. Clicking my python file will open it in gedit, I use the terminal to run codes

Comment: are you using Python2 or 3? @noobcoder

Comment: I use python3 @Axium

Comment: try `py "filename.py"`, of course replacing filename.py with your actual filename

Comment: In the argument provided to "action" ? Already did that. Just opens up a new tab and says can't find the file :(

Comment: Perhaps this could be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button

Comment: Use Ajax , call API use a microframwork in the python script like flask or Falcon

Comment: Yes, thank you @JibinMathews , I used Flask. Sorry for the late reply.