# A safe way to make an website run a python script

Tags: python, html

I made a small script that solves an combinatorial optimization problem and I would like put it in a website so users can "play" with it, they could send a list of "points" to the server and this script would use a database to return the best combination of these "points".

The problem is I do not have much experience in web dev. I searched how to make an html button execute an script and I found this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button#:~:text=To%20run%2C%20open%20command%20prompt,Hope%20this%20helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button#:%7E:text=To%20run%2C%20open%20command%20prompt,Hope%20this%20helpful).

But there says that an html button calling an python script is not safe. So what would be ideal What would be an ideal, safe alternative so that I could make sure that anyone who accesses my website can execute this script safely?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on some other SE network, although I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that comes to mind would be setting up some Python-API (e.g. with Flask) which you could call with HTTP via JS, having different routes for different usages.
Here's a [short overview of Flask](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask#overview) showcasing how it could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no "easy" answer to your question.  What you'd really need to do is to *create a web-site in Python* on your host computer – using a tool such as Django – and have one of the URLs supported by that website call your script.

Honestly, "what you're asking for here, really isn't the sort of question that *StackOverflow* is intended to answer."  It's too big.  Another one of the SE-family sites might be more appropriate, although I'm not quite sure which one ...