# When I click on a button written in html(vs code), it will run a code written in python. Can I do that?

Tags: python, html, flask

Well I am working on a project where I want to click on a button(html) and it will run a python code in Pycharm(or any ide). For front end I am using Vs code. Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button/48552490

Comment: To be a bit more correct, vs code is not a front-end nor is pycharm a back-end, front-end consists of html, css and js, while back-end can be python, php, and/or other languages, also this means that you can't directly run python code in html

Answer (score 0):

You can try flask and write an HTML template.
With a button in HTML can `GET` or `POST` method to reach some flask route，then you can run some python code you want.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/endpoint')
def point():
    # some python code
    pass
app.run()
```

Comment: Well I want to run the code from .html file. Which will direct to the python code. It is possible with the GET and POST method right? As I'm getting "Cannot GET /my-link/" error.

Comment: can you show me your code?

Comment: I want to click a button from .html file, then it should run .py file. As i am already running server from vs code, do I still need to run it from python? I am following the first code(answer) from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button

Comment: Solved though. Thank you for helping.