# Why is it dangerous to run python script using angular?

Tags: python, html, angular

I was wondering if I can run a python script which is in my laptop using a button on my angular app and came across the info that its a dangerous practice to run python scripts using html. But why is it dangerous nobody tells.

Comment: You have to clarify what you are planning. It is not possible to run a Python script directly from HTML. There has to be something inbetween.

Comment: 1) We don’t know what this “info” is (or if it is even accurately represented in the question — *provide links to resources used in claims*); 2) One generally can’t run Python “using html” anyway (making this “info” or representation of such suspect — *provide links to resources used in claims*).

Comment: in theory it runs python in your server ... if someone malicious was able to access your http page they could wreck your server by running python code...

Comment: @KlausD. this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button/48552490. I came across while researching. Have a look at the comment made by user mdatsev