# run python script from within html in the browser

Tags: python, html

**This is a python inside html question**.

I have been looking for some time and have come across this code that embeds `python` inside a webpage (html).

I have tested it and it works. Here is the code:

The code script is saved as `*.html` and opens (and runs) in the browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vanillawc/wc-code@1.0.3/src/wc-code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <wc-code mode="python">
    <script type="wc-content">
       a = 1
       b = 1
       print(a+b)
    </script>
  </wc-code>                                                                                         
</body>
```

The `<script>` tag in the code above contains some basic `python` code.

However, i cannot seem to import modules with a standard `import module` call and was wondering if there was a way of doing this ?

Also, similarly, if there is a way of calling or importing a custom python script like `my_code.py` ?

Thanks

Comment: is it possible for you to use PHP? then i have a simple solution...

Comment: Perhaps https://openerp-web-v7.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn flask or Django \

the solution here [FLASK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53944884/18589093) can be helpful

Comment: both `flask` and `django` are web frameworks. So inherently different as cannot run the cde directly from the browser (which is sometimes more convenient). They are launched from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

[Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide) is a solution for embedding python inside a webpage.

Comment: The snipped of code in the question is from one of the links from Pyodid. That is where i got this code from. But can one import other modules from within the browser or is it just native python without modules ?

Comment: do you have an example of importing modules (assuming that this feature exists) ?

Comment: It seems pyodide doesn't ship all modules. Pl see https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/packages-in-pyodide.html for the list of standard packages.

Comment: Pyodide documentation says that additional packages can be imported using micropip. Pl go through https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/micropip-api.html.

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be achievable by using [`PyScript`](https://pyscript.net/). You can use the import statements inside the `<py-script>` tag.

Live Demo **:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<py-script>
  from datetime import datetime
  datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
</py-script>
```

Note (As per the current official documentation) **:**

> PyScript is very alpha and under heavy development. There are many
> known issues, from usability to loading times, and you should expect
> things to change often. We encourage people to play and explore with
> PyScript, but at this time we do not recommend using it for
> production.