# Is there a way to open a tkinter window just from an html button itself?

Tags: python, html, tkinter, button

I am trying to have user inputs saved to a JSON file - I have tried that with only HTML and js but it never worked.
However I know how to save inputs to a JSON using python:
I have a very simple Tkinter window, which should serve as a form and all I need is a way
to open this tkinter window from a plain HTML-Button.

Is there a way to do that?
..and if that's impossible, are there alternatives?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. Do you have any Python you can share?

Comment: there are a number of solutions answering the same question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552343/how-can-i-execute-a-python-script-from-an-html-button